# SEH handler cause compiler warnings and errors

Tags: exception, seh

I use a SEH handler in my code, like this:

```
__try
{
   // code...
}
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
  TRACE(_T("Exception"));
}
```

but get the following compiler errors:

```
e:\test.cpp(3310): warning C4509: nonstandard extension used: 'CMyClass::Test' uses SEH and 'iterator' has destructor
e:\test.cpp(3290): see declaration of 'iterator'
e:\test.cpp(3450): error C2712: Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just what the error message says: you can not use SEH in functions that require destructors to be called. You can always put that `__try`/`__except` block into a sub-function.

**Edit:** You can make that function static, but in my tests the compiler didn't inline it, not even with `__forceinline`.